# How to undo Unicoins changes

Tags: discussion, support

I used the Uniconis to make modifications but now I do not like what I got.

Is there a way to undo the modifications like scrolling title bar ect.

What is Unicoins:

It is a popup on the right hand site top on the ask differant and it looks like this.

[image: Unicoins]

More about Unicoins:

[image: about unicoins]

Comment: What is Uniconis?

Comment: Ah, that's probably just the April 1st joke, so it will disappear again tomorrow :-)

Comment: Did I fall for it again :(

Comment: It is well done and it actually works as promised :)

Comment: They did fool me but it was well done and fun...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a power by 'recycling' the power — this costs 10 coins though.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed the Aprils Fools joke of SE this year.

You can follow the humor, discussion and confusion at [SO Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicoins) and by logging out of the site, you will see that nothing has actually changed on your account.